# C# Store 3gpp file from Android stream

Tags: c#, android, .net, file, backend

I have backend server that's receive chunk byte array over socket whiteout fileheader parts
need to store this data playable, but whiteout header it can not play.

how can i store this data ??
Android side code

```
int intRecordSampleRate = AudioTrack.getNativeOutputSampleRate(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

intBufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(intRecordSampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

audioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC
        , intRecordSampleRate,
        AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO,
        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
        intBufferSize);

audioRecord.startRecording();

byte[] data = new byte[intBufferSize];

while (isActive) {

    audioRecord.read(data, 0, data.length);

//Send data here
}
```

Comment: You dont have to tell us. We all know.

Comment: @blackapps , i need solution !!